# Drag link from Internet Explorer to Windows Application

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, win32com, oledragdrop

I'm trying to implement dragging of link urls from webbrowsers to a Win32 application. It works fine using Firefox and Google Chrome, the link shows up as text in my `IDataObject` structure. But when dragging a link from Internet Explorer it seems to block it somehow.

Using the `EnumFormatEtc` and `GetClipboardFormatName` functions I can detect that the `IDataObject` contains three formats; *UntrustedDragDrop*, *msSourceUrl* and *DragImageBits*.

However, it seems I cant extract any data using `IDataObject->QueryGetData(...)` and `IDataObject->GetData(...)`, I've tried using the corresponding enums to the formats.

Is dragging links out of internet explorer simply forbidden, or is it any way I can get around this and read the link?

Comment: Guess I need someone who developed WinOLE for this one...

Comment: Please show your actual code. What errors are `(Query)GetData()` actually reporting? Also, `GetClipboardFormatName()` only works with formats that were registered dynamically using `RegisterClipboardFormat()`, but the `IDataObject` can hold [standard pre-defined formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx) as well, are you taking those into account?